# Converting $r=(x^2+y^2+z^2)^{1/2}$ cartesian coordinates to spherical coordinates

Tags: cylindrical-coordinates

Let $r=(x^2+y^2+z^2)^{1/2}$ be the radial distance from the origin expressed in cartesian coordinates.

I have been asked to express this in cylindrical coordinates.

Is $r=(x^2+y^2+z^2)^{1/2}$ the same as $r=x\hat{e}_x + y\hat{e}_y + z\hat{e}_z$

if yes then to convert to cartesian coordinate:

- $R=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}=R$
- $\theta=tan^{-1}(\frac{y}{x})=tan^{-1}===??$
- $z=z$

i dont' understand what values we have put in?

Answer (score 1):

You have to use these $$\left\{\begin{aligned}x&=\rho \cos \varphi \\y&=\rho \sin \varphi \\z&=z\end{aligned}\right.$$
in order to convert from cartesian to cylindrical coordinates.

$r=(x^2+y^2+z^2)^{1/2}$ becomes $r=(\rho^2+z^2)^{1/2}$